# Get values from JSON using Visual Basic

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone

I am making a Windows Phone app (for IP tracking). Now, I want to get values from JSON, but the webbrowser doesn't open it.

Here, textbox1 is where we have to enter IP address. And the url is

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn=
```

Now, when we press a button, the URL becomes something like

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn=(IP address here)
```

(CODE)

```
 Dim url As String = "http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn=" + textbox1.Text
```

But the following URL is JSON. I want to get details like Country, Lat, Long, Population etc...I have tried many ways, but I can't sort it out.

Please help me by visiting link.

Now, I get an error in BeginGerResponse, Code Here :

```
 Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn=49.213.47.141"), HttpWebRequest)
        response = DirectCast(request.BeginGetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

This is what I have recently done. I get error in BeginGetResponse. It says 'Over resolution failed accuse no accesible 'BeginGet Respone'....'

Comment: If you look at the JSON returned, it has the fields `geobyteslongitude` and `geobyteslatitude`, as well as fields for Coutnry etc. Look at parsing JSON with VB - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d8fd1f4-69b2-4355-b6aa-76e581dc7298/parse-json-response-to-array-using-vb?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: What have you tried? If you have tried "many ways," let us know what they are so. This lets us know whether to suggest a new way, or if something is wrong elsewhere in your program.

Comment: Listen. I have to desrialize json from URL, not from a string!

Comment: Get the URL response to a string and deserialize it

Comment: NOTE...I want to desiralize it directly from link. Please Help me!

Comment: why do you think you need to deserialize "directly from link"?  The link is a json response.  it is a string.  it is meant to be read into your app.  the JS deserializers all work on a string, not a URL.

Comment: Okay...I will try it.

Comment: Ummm. Can you give me an example which gives value to text box or textblock. Pls give me an example by visiting link!

Comment: when you deserialize it, it will give you a collection of 21 named items. just get them by name (e.g. "geobytescountry").  Your comment of `in url there is 'geobytescountry'` *sounds like* you dont know how to post a request and read a response.  There is no `geobytescountry` in the URL, it is in the *response*.  The JSON serializers work on response strings.  Deserializing would be very complex if they had to be configured for web access.

Comment: Oh. I can;t do that. Can anyone please give me an example to get value from it to a texbox/textblock??? PLS